# How to implement Snap-to-cell on a UITableView using Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, scroll

I have 3 rows, each with a height of 80% of the screen size. The behaviour I'm looking for is (and struggling to implement in Swift) is when the user starts scrolling to should "snap-to" the next cell. In other words if it goes beyond the middle of the row it should then scroll forward to display all the cell and stop.

It's a simple UITableView within a UITableViewController in Swift.

**EDIT / UPDATE:**
I was trying to create the behaviour of a PageController but with vertical scroll by using ScrollView. I can use a PageController and set the navigation direction to vertical - Problem solved.

Comment: Can you explain better this line _if it goes beyond the middle of the row it should then scroll forward to display all the cell and stop_, please

Comment: Sure. So each row is 80% height of the entire screen. When scrolling, if the middle of the row passes the middle of the screen it should snap to the next row. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes of course, thanks for the aclaration. I'll try to put an answer ASAP

Answer (score 1):

*You can use the UIScrollViewDelegate methods on UITableView to accomplish this*

**Swift 4.2**

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var visibleRect = CGRect()

    visibleRect.origin = tableView.contentOffset
    visibleRect.size = tableView.bounds.size
    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: visiblePoint) 
        else { return }
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

**Note That This Code Will Only Make The Cell Snap, Once The TableView Is Done "Scrolling"**

*What I did to get around it was to add a time delay on whenever I stopped dragging my finger on the screen, and then it will snap*

I accomplished this by using another UIScrollViewDelegate methods on UITableView called `scrollViewWillEndDragging`....like so:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView,
    withVelocity velocity: CGPoint,
    targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.8) {
        self.scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView)
    }
}
```

change the delay `0.8` to whatever you want!

Comment: I am using let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.origin.x, y:  visibleRect.origin.y + cellHeight/2.0) instead

Comment: Nice! Thanks @castillejoale

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, this is how I'd try to solve your problem. Declare a property in your view controller that stores the vertical position of the touch that starts the scrolling. Better yet, store the content offset of the scroll view in question (the table view). You'd set its value in the delegate method `scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_:)` because that's the method that gets called when the scrolling is just about to start. Then, in `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` you'd keep track of how far from that vertical position the scrolling has progressed so far. When it's gone past half the height of a cell (I'm assuming all 3 cells have the same height), then cancel the scrolling and, instead, set the scroll view's content offset manually to snap it into its final position.